# Facing issue setting up gerrit with LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, gerrit

Following is what I have given in my gerrit.config

```
 [ldap]
         server = ldaps://ldap.corp.flipkart.com
         username = rohan.bajaj,dc=flipkart,dc=com
         accountBase = ou=People,dc=flipkart,dc=com
         groupBase = ou=Groups,dc=flipkart,dc=com

Getting the following error:

ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.auth.ldap.LdapRealm : Cannot query LDAP to autenticate user
javax.naming.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems in the username entry you need to write like below:

username = cn=rohan.bajaj,dc=flipkart,dc=com

In your case you may try depending on your ldap username. i.e. it could be either "cn" or "uid" etc.